# What are the benefits of using Linkedlists over Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I'm a self-taught developer and I'm currently learning data structures in Javascript. In Javascript, arrays are already dynamic. Arrays are easier to implement too so, why are linkedlists needed?

Are there any other benefits of using linkedlists in javascript over arrays, in terms of time complexity or memory?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the benefits of arrays and linkedlist in short and crisp are:-

**Arrays:**

1- Contiguous block of memory.

2- O(1) random access.

3- O(n) time for insertions/deletions as elements may need to be shifted.

4- Lower memory overhead.

**Linked Lists:**

1- Non-contiguous memory (nodes with references).

2- O(n) access time as you may need to traverse.

3- Faster insertions/deletions due to updating references.

4- Higher memory overhead.

Comment: Some of those aren't benefits...